# Are there any verses in the Quran which refer to the Punishment of the Grave?

Tags: quran, tafseer, punishment, grave, verses

**Opinion**

**I believe that Grave Punishment Exist**

Some people are looking for that, is there any verse in Quran about of the grave punishment? Some people are disagree about of the grave punishment, also some people asked that to me,
there are some difference of opinion also in the Muslim People .

**Note** I read those verses (Below) and also some scholars say that those verses indicate/refer to the Grave Punishment  and also I read and heard from some people, Who are  refer those  verse to the grave punishment..

**Question**

*What I am looking for?*

if I anything I misunderstood please mention and Is there any more verse in The Holy Quran, Which are refer/indicate to The Grave Punishment, please  Give it, also I will be happy if anyone provide tefsser for below those verse...

**Praise be to Allah & Allah Know the Best & Secret**

**First Verse**

يُضَـٰعَفۡ لَهُ ٱلۡعَذَابُ يَوۡمَ ٱلۡقِيَـٰمَةِ وَيَخۡلُدۡ فِيهِۦ مُهَانًا
Multiplied for him is the punishment on the Day of Resurrection, and he will abide therein humiliated
From  [this link](https://qurano.com/en/25-al-furqan/verse-69/) many of them  translate this word يُضَـٰعَفۡ     as Doubled.

**Surah Al-Furqan Verse 69 | 25:69 Quran**

This verse refers to the grave punishment. (Allah Know the Best & Secret )

what is the meaning of Doubled?

Example As : I paid someone 5 dollar for work, when I Hired him second time , I promised that I will pay doubled amount, before what amount I gave

In general sense I understood that  Allah will give one punishment before on the Day of Resurrection. on the Day of Resurrection, It will double/multiplied

**Second Verse**

And among those around you of the bedouins are hypocrites, and [also] from the people of Madinah. They have become accustomed to hypocrisy. You, [O Muhammad], do not know them, [but] We know them. We will punish them twice [in this world]; then they will be returned to a great punishment.

**Surah At-Tawba Verse 101 | 09: 101 Quran**  [link](https://qurano.com/en/9-at-tawba/verse-101/)

in this verse *We will punish them twice* also indicate/refer to the grave punishment

Third Verse
“The Day their plan will not avail them at all, nor will they be helped. And indeed, for those who have wronged is a punishment before that, but most of them do not know.” -

**Surah At-Tur Verse 46-47| 52: 46- 47 Quran** [link](https://qurano.com/en/52-at-tur/verse-46/)
[link](https://qurano.com/en/52-at-tur/verse-47/)

The term “punishment before that” refers that before the ultimate judgment day disbelievers and wrongdoers will face torment and punishment in their graves.

**Fourth Verse**

Every soul will taste death. And you will only receive your full reward on the Day of Judgment. Whoever is spared from the Fire and is admitted into Paradise will ˹indeed˺ triumph, whereas the life of this world is no more than the delusion of enjoyment.

***Surah Al-Imaran Verse 185 | 03: 185 Quran***

``you will only receive your full reward on the Day of Judgment'' also refer to the grave punishment   (Allah Know the Best & Secret )

as a Muslim I know that, Sometimes Allah reward people instantly for their good/bad deeds. If not reward instantly, Allah will reward you on the Day of Judgment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following verses are among those cited by scholars as evidence for, or references to, the Punishment of the grave  ( عذاب القبر ) within the Quran:

> #### النار يعرضون عليها غدوا وعشيا ويوم تقوم الساعة أدخلوا آل فرعون أشد العذاب
>
> The Fire, they are exposed to it morning and evening. And the Day the Hour appears [it will be said], "Make the people of Pharaoh enter the severest punishment."
>
> <sup>— [Quran 40:46](http://quran.com/40/46)</sup>

The people of Pharoah are punished with fire now morning and evening, and on the day of judgement they will enter into the severest punishment in Hell. The first punishment which is happening now is their punishment of the grave. Refer to [Tafsir al-Qurtubi](https://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/qortobi/sura40-aya46.html#qortobi) and [Tafsir al-Razi](https://shamela.ws/book/23635/4922#p8).

---

> #### مما خطيئاتهم أغرقوا فأدخلوا نارا فلم يجدوا لهم من دون الله أنصارا
>
> Because of their sins they were drowned and put into the Fire, and they found not for themselves besides Allah [any] helpers.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 71:25](http://quran.com/71/25)</sup>

The people of Noah were put into fire right after being drowned. This evidences the punishment of the grave, since it can not mean the fire of Hell as they can only enter that after the Day of Judgement which has not come yet. Refer to [Tafsir al-Qurtubi](https://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/qortobi/sura71-aya25.html#qortobi) and [Tafsir al-Razi](https://shamela.ws/book/23635/5734)

---

> #### سنعذبهم مرتين ثم يردون إلى عذاب عظيم
>
> We will punish them twice [in this world]; then they will be returned to a great punishment.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 9:101](http://quran.com/9/101)</sup>

The second punishment is the punishment of the grave. Refer to [Tafsir al-Tabary](https://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/tabary/sura9-aya101.html#tabary)

---

> #### وإن للذين ظلموا عذابا دون ذلك ولكن أكثرهم لا يعلمون
>
> And indeed, for those who have wronged is a punishment before that, but most of them do not know.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 52:47](http://quran.com/52/47)</sup>

This verse evidences that there is a punishment for the disbelievers *before* the Day of Judgement, that includes punishment of the grave. Refer to [Tafsir al-Tabary](https://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/tabary/sura52-aya47.html#tabary).

---

> #### ومن أعرض عن ذكري فإن له معيشة ضنكا ونحشره يوم القيامة أعمى
>
> And whoever turns away from My remembrance - indeed, he will have a depressed life, and We will gather him on the Day of Resurrection blind.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 20:124](http://quran.com/20/124)</sup>

Depressed life is explained by some of the exegetes as a reference to the punishment of the grave. This has also been narrated from the Prophet Muhammad ﷺ, see [Sahih ibn Hibban](https://shamela.ws/book/537/5471) and [Tafsir Tabari](https://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/tabary/sura20-aya124.html#tabary) etc.

---

> #### يثبت الله الذين آمنوا بالقول الثابت في الحياة الدنيا وفي الآخرة ويضل الله الظالمين ويفعل الله ما يشاء
>
> Allah keeps firm those who believe, with the firm word, in worldly life and in the Hereafter. And Allah sends astray the wrongdoers. And Allah does what He wills.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 14:27](http://quran.com/14/27)</sup>

It is reported from the Prophet Muhammad ﷺ that this verse was revealed about the questioning and punishment of the grave, see [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:2871a) and [Sahih Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:1369) etc.

---

> #### ألهاكم التكاثر حتى زرتم المقابر كلا سوف تعلمون ثم كلا سوف تعلمون
>
> Competition in [worldly] increase diverts you
> Until you visit the graveyards.
> No! You are going to know.
> Then no! You are going to know.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 102:1-4](http://quran.com/102/1-4)</sup>

Some of the exegetes have noted that this is about the punishment of the grave, the repetition is because the first instance refers to the punishment of the grave and the second to that of the Day of Judgement, refer to [Tafsir al-Tabary](https://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/tabary/sura102-aya2.html#tabary) and [Tafsir al-Qurtubi](https://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/qortobi/sura102-aya4.html#qortobi).

Comment: tanks for provide new verse

Comment: is there any English version of _Tafsir al-Qurtubi_ links ? would you know and  would can give me the link ? it will help me a lot.. tahks ...

Comment: No there is no english translation of Tafsir al-Qurtubi as far as I am aware. [Aisha Bewley](https://www.amazon.com/Books-Aisha-Bewley/s?rh=n%3A283155%2Cp_27%3AAisha+Bewley) has done some work on it, but it is incomplete and abridged.